# Installing the JIRA Mobile Connect SDK on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, jira, jira-plugin

I have download the Whole code from JIRA Mobile connect's home site but
I have facing this issue while install the JIRA Mobile connect,All the things is perfect but in  My project i have one JMCViewController.xib and it contain one scrollview and the class assign to that scrollview is JMCScrollViewContainer and that is missing so How to find that class, I have tried all the things but not get success so can any one solve this problem? Please help
Thanx in Advance for any Help Any Suggestion,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These classes were added recently so you will need to manually add them.

You can get them from here https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jiraconnect-ios/src/0f2c90244acd/JIRAConnect/JMCClasses/Core/views